# Местоимение "Наш" в роли дополнения и обстоятельства

Tags: дополнение, определения, местоимения

Пожалуйста, помогите!!! В каком случае местоимение "Наш" будет не определением, а дополнением? Если возможно, то и обстоятельство.

Answer (score 1):

Если слово НАШ выступает в роли существительного, то оно может быть дополнением:

***Спроси у НАШЕГО, он знает.***

Обстоятельство: ***Он спрашивал на немецком, а я отвечал на нашем.***

Answer (score 1):

Дополнение - "поживём у наших (у родни); в поговорках Знай наших (нас); И нашим и вашим.

Обстоятельство - Будет по-нашему. (как?)